# Selenium is not searching on a webpage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

so I am trying to search for a car in the website [www.copart.com/](http://www.copart.com/) as practice for a project. I am trying to search with the lot number (72486533) in the search box yet its not searching it for some reason and showing an error. please let me know what's wrong with this disappointing code.
(also if someone could recommend an updated selenium course that would be amazing, I am new to coding)
this is my attempt:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys



#idk what these two lines are, it helps not close the tab immediately.
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.copart.com/")

search = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'mobile-input-search')
search.send_keys("72486533")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 0):

You rely on wrong input. Input you get is for mobile view and it is invisible.
For web needed input has selector `#input-search` .
Also I suggest to wait until search results are rendered, for example, by waiting for visibility of element `.title-and-highlights`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.copart.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'input-search')))
search.send_keys("72486533")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[type=submit]').click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'title-and-highlights')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may should handle the consent popup first to interact with your search:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[aria-label="Consent"]'))).click()
```

This needs following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

##### Example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.copart.com/")

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[aria-label="Consent"]'))).click()
search = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'mobile-input-search')
search.send_keys("72486533")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```